# Non metallic currency

Tags: internal-consistency, currency

So i have this world with lots of small city state like kingdoms. 
And i want them to all have their own currency but to have some diversity i do not want all of them to use the standard medieval/fantasy coin system of copper/bronze/silver/gold and thought about some other materials but wanted to know if there is any historical precedent for these things to be used as money.

First thing i thought of were coins not made of metal but of wood, stone and some more exotic things like polished crystal and maybe even polished coral all fashioned into coin like shapes.

Is there any historical use of these types of materials as coins/currency?

Edit: I know shells like cowrie have been used in the past i just wondered if the materials i listed or other unusual materials have also ever been used.

Comment: This is question for history.se and worldbuilding. Stones, shells (cowrie), and paper.

Comment: [calcite + oral history](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rai_stones) note that the location of the stone is not important, only the known/verified existence of it.

Comment: cocoa,salt, and rice.

Comment: Leather (of the full-grain, high-quality, embossed variety) and porcelain have both been used in the past

Comment: Salt - once so valuable that salt mines were as secure as gold mines are today.  Very valuable as a preservative of foods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Anything that can be assigned some sort of value can be used as a currency, and probably has been at some point.

Now of course the leaves of Golgafrincham Ark Fleet Ship B are particularly portable and low value, but as an example of the opposite extreme of what's been used as a currency, consider the [Rai stones of Yap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rai_stones).

> The Micronesian island of Yap is known for its stone money, known as Rai (Yapese: raay), or Fei: large doughnut-shaped, carved disks of (usually) calcite, up to 4 m (13 ft) in diameter (most are much smaller). The smallest can be as little as 3.5 centimetres (1.4 in) in diameter. There are around 6,000 of the large, circular stone disks carved out of limestone formed from aragonite and calcite crystals. Rai stones were quarried on several of the Micronesian islands, mainly Palau, but briefly on Guam as well, and transported to Yap for use as money. They have been used in trade by the Yapese as a form of currency.

Simple limestone doesn't have much value in Europe for example, but on Yap it was accepted as currency, but more importantly the actual handing over of the currency wasn't a thing.

> The monetary system of Yap relies on an oral history of ownership. In the case of stones that are too large to move, buying an item with one simply involves agreeing that the ownership has changed. As long as the transaction is recorded in the oral history, it will now be owned by the person to whom it is passed and no physical movement of the stone is required.

An understanding of how much financial transactions can differ from what we conventionally understand shows you quite how much freedom you have when you want to deviate from a simple convention like currency.

*The real risk is how much time you want to spend explaining how your currency or other medium of exchange works, and how that explanation detracts from the flow of action.*

Comment: As I recall, there were stones that were moved, but lost to the seas (The transporting boat sunk). But being stone, they know they are still there, somewhere, in the water, and so the "lost" stones were still valid currency.